# How to insert data in Oracle table with virtual column through Entityframework

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have entityframework with database first approach. And one of the table have virtual column. On adding data to this table, getting error disallowed to insert. So how to handle this scenario?

Comment: Did you try [`DatabaseGenerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=net-5.0)  [annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) with `Computed` value?

Comment: Database Generated doesn't worked. Also this annotation will only ensure EF should pass value for a column or not but for successful insert, i have to somehow remove this column i guess